# Secure WCF Data Service on website that is not running with a SSL certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, security, wcf-data-services

I have a website that I use as a service. The clients are c# console applications and NOT browsers. Therefore I can post encrypted objects back and forth because my clients are c# console applications.

Anyways because I dont want my clients (console applications) to connect directly to the database. I have added a `WCF Data service` to my website. The problem is that now I do not have control on how to encrypt the data. **Is there a way I can configure that service so that my clients can establish a secure connection to the `WCF data service` even though the website does NOT have a SSL certificate?**

### Edit

On the WCF data service I have overriden:

```
protected override MyEntities CreateDataSource()
{
   // etc
```

and based if the user posted the correct encrypted object I will enable him to connect to the database. What about the response? that part will not be encrypted right? How can I encrypt it?

### Edit 2

I think my solution is to make the web service a WCF service since my clients are console applications right? That way it will be secure? I cannot add a WCF Data Service to a WCF class library project though.

Comment: Once again. I must ask the same question regarding security. What do you want to secure AGAINST?

Comment: To elaborate on Aron's question: is it enough for the communication to simply be difficult for others to decrypt? Or do you also want other aspects of security, like resistance to replay attacks, and confirmation that the server is who it says it is (anti-spoofing)?

Comment: Sorry you are right. I want to prevent others from decrypting the information as it may be confidentials. Any other attacks that I am not aware off I will appreciate at least knowing them thanks!

Comment: @TonoNam that does not answer the question. Without specific context, I can only say that NO its not secure. SSL is not just about encryption. Its about key exchange, its about replay attack, in some case, even forward security. Either describe your adversary, or learn all these terms. The main one that SSL secures against is man-in-middle without pre-shared keys.

Comment: I exchange public and private keys with a library on my console application. after that I have the same symmetric key saved on the session. I am just missing to get data from the database without having to create a different page for each entity as. GetCustomers.aspx, GetProducts.aspx, Its so tedious and I know its not the right way of doing it...

Comment: @TonoNam are you rolling your own security protocol? PLEASE FOR THE LOVE OF GOD STOP! How are you protecting against Man in Middle? Is the symmetric key forward secure? How do you ensure that the session key has enough entropy?

Comment: since both web service and client are console applications I chose this approach. I first send the web service my public key. The webserivce encrypts a random sym key. Then on any other message I encrypt the time and I also apply a random mask. I have seen that with program like fiddler I can see whats being exchanged between server and client. But you are right I will use SSL because there is no way to have security on the WCF Data service without it

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Tunnel HTTP communications inside another secure channel, like TLS (in which case it's difficult to see why you wouldn't want to just use it),
- Write a serializer that secures your individual payloads (HTTP resources such as ATOM or JSON data), in which case you would create a new media type,
- Encrypt/sign individual properties of your model, and store/embed them as such in your database/messages.

There are certainly other extension points, but these seem to cover most use-cases.

I suggest you refine your question or post new questions with more precise requirements, so that you can get better answers.  I would also suggest you include a little bit of context as well, because most people will rightly wonder if your problem isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  The reason for that is that implementing secure protocols is more difficult that one would typically imagine.  Yes, the theory is extremely simple -- share a public key here, sign and encrypt a symmetric key there, encrypt a payload over there -- but the truth is that high-level cryptographic abstractions are extremely leaky.  All your assumptions about what's really going on very often turn out to be false on at least a couple of edge cases, and before you know it your little security project takes a dimension of its own.